# Using Google Calendar API with a Python 3.7 Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I'm having some trouble while running a Python 3.7 Google Cloud Function that is supposed to list the events of my Google Calendar. I'm using the Google Calendar API.

This is my code.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
import datetime
from apiclient.discovery import build
import datetime
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def listEvents(request):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credential.json',scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'],)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    return('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    if not events:
        return('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        return(start, event['summary'])
```

I'm using the App Engine service account as the function identity and its key is the json credential.json that I reference in credentials variable above. This json file is packed in the function bundle at its root (image attached). Additionally, I've shared my calendar with the service account e-mail, directly inside the Google Calendar APP.

The function is deployed OK, but when testing it I find the following errors:

```
2020-03-17 12:10:51.851 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 Function execution started
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.7.11-py3.7.egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 from google.appengine.api import memcache
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.7.11-py3.7.egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-03-17 12:10:51.915 GMTfunction-1wdeeo5kwk4p0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `cache_discovery=False` flag need to be declared when building your service.*

#### Fix:

Under the assumption you have google.appengine installed using

```
pip install googleappengine
```

You need to change:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

to:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
```